# What is the greatest $4$-digit integer for which the sum of its proper divisors is $n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What is the greatest  $4$-digit integer $n$ for which the sum of its proper divisors is $n-1$?

I can't think of a way to solve this without guessing and checking.

Edit: It is easy to show that all powers of $2$ are such numbers. But are they the only numbers?

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of divisor function ?

Comment: Yes, for example the sum of the divisors of $6$ is $(1+2)(1+3)$.

Comment: But it isn't equal to $n$ it is equal to $n-1$ right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Where did the $+1$ come from?

Comment: Also this question is meant to be solved in under $45$ seconds.

Comment: What can be said about the sum of the proper divisors of powers of $2$ in general? I think that will help since the you really just need to find the largest power of $2$ less than $10000$

Comment: The proper divisors of $2^n$ are $1, 2, 2^2, \ldots, 2^{n-1}$. The sum of these is $2^n-1$.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But prove that powers of $2$ are the only such numbers.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the sum of the proper divisors of $n$ is equal to $n-1$ if and only if $n$ is a perfect power of $2$, hence the answer to your question would be $8192$.

Comment: @barak manos Yes but prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the definition of "proper divisor" of $n$ ? Like proper subgroup, or proper ideal, I think it can also mean that $1$ and $n$ are not proper. In that case we look for the largest positive integer $n<10000$ with $\sigma(n)=(n-1)+1+n=2n$, hence for a perfect number less that $10^4$. This is $n=8128$.

In case, $\sigma(n)=2n-1$, $n$ is called [*almost perfect*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPerfectNumber.html). The only known almost perfect numbers are the powers of $2$. It is *not known* whether there are others, see the link. So then the answer is, as already remarked, $n=8192$.

Comment: Yes, but in this case we ARE considering $1$ and are NOT considering $n$ in our count.

Comment: @Puzzled417 OK, if this is what you mean, then my answer is not helpful. It was so tempting to come up with perfect numbers - sorry.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I deleted my earlier comment because the end of the article I linked to mentioned that sometimes "proper" does mean excluding $1$ as well. So while I haven't seen it before, it does seem to be a thing.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes but how many people know off the top of their heads that $8128$ is a perfect number?

Comment: @Puzzled417 You would be surprised how many people know this. Our department gets letters on perfect numbers every day. Less on Fermat nowadays.

Comment: Prove that the sum of the proper divisors of $n$ is equal to $n-1$ iff $n$ is a power of $2$ then I will accept is as the answer.

Comment: @Puzzled417 I will not be able to prove it, because it is an open conjecture. So checking is the only way.

Comment: This question is for a middle school math competition. I don't think this could be an open problem or that would be very challenging.

Comment: If anyone can prove to me that the sum of the proper divisors of $n$ is equal to $n-1$ iff $n$ is a power of $2$ then I will be very happy.

Comment: If anyone could prove that, they would be very happy on their own.

Comment: @Puzzled417, can you give a reference to the competition where this appeared?  I for one cannot think of any simple way to be sure there are no other such integers between $2^{13}$ and $10^4$ that doesn't involve a lot of case-by-case checking.  It makes me wonder if there is something missing from the statement of the problem.

Comment: It appeared in the 2014 Mathcounts state countdown round (it's question 28):https://www.mathcounts.org/sites/default/files/u1706/MATHCOUNTS%202014%20State%20Competition%20-%20CDR.pdf

Comment: @Puzzled417, thank you very much for the reference.  My guess now is that the problem simply rewards students who intuit that the answer must be a power of $2$ (since all they have to give is the correct numerical answer).

Comment: @Barry Cirpa Yes but I prefer that when I solve math questions I know that my answer is correct.

Comment: @Puzzled417, given the constraints of the competition (45-second time limit, no calculator allowed), I'm hard pressed to imagine how anyone could get the answer with absolute confidence.

Answer (score 0):

I get $8192$. This is also $2^{13}$, which I'm sure is significant. I was lazy and programmed it. Its divisors are 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096.

```
using System;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{

    int result = 9999;

    for (int i = 9999; i >= 1000; i--)
    {
        if (SumOfDivisors(i) == i - 1)
        {
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

//Sums the proper divisors of n
static int SumOfDivisors(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```